# Change name of folders recursively - Bash

Tags: bash, rename

I want to rename all files called `Caudate_masks` to lower case: `caudate_masks`.

In my directory I have several folders, one of them called `Controls` and other one called `Patients`. Inside each one of them you can find the `Caudate_masks` folders.

```
   Controls

   └───C01
   │   └─── Caudate_masks
   │   └─── ...     
   └───C02
   │   └─── Caudate_masks
   │   └─── ...
   └───C03
   │   └─── Caudate_masks
   │   └─── ...


   Patients

   └───H01
   │   └─── Caudate_masks
   │   └─── ...
```

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="/media/roy/Analysis"
for group in Controls Patients; do
    cd $DIR/$group || exit
    for folder in *; do
        for cortical in "$folder/"*; do
            if [ $cortical = "$folder/Caudate_masks" ]; then
                mv $cortical caudate_masks
            fi
        done;
    done;
done;
```

If I execute:

```
if [ $cortical = "$folder/Caudate_masks" ]; then
                echo $cortical
```

I get a list of all the folders of interest, however, `mv $cortical caudate_masks` doesn´t change names, but move files, and `rename` doesn´t appear as a valid function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `rename` package:

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Then it's a shell one-liner:

```
[sh @ balrog] ~/tmp 27 % tree
.
├── a
│   └── Caudate_masks
├── b
│   └── Caudate_masks
└── c
    └── Caudate_masks

6 directories, 0 files

[sh @ balrog] ~/tmp 28 % rename 's/Caudate_masks/caudate_masks/' **/Caudate_masks

[sh @ balrog] ~/tmp 29 % tree
.
├── a
│   └── caudate_masks
├── b
│   └── caudate_masks
└── c
    └── caudate_masks

6 directories, 0 files
```

Notice that modern shells (bash, zsh) support the `**` wildcard which means "somewhere in this directory tree".

---

The reason why your script doesn't work as expected is that in this snippet

```
        for cortical in "$folder/"*; do
            if [ $cortical = "$folder/Caudate_masks" ]; then
                mv $cortical caudate_masks
            fi
        done;
```

your old name contains the directory (from `$folder`), yet the new name does not. It should work if you change that line to

```
                mv $cortical $folder/caudate_masks
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to / can't install `rename`, then you could use the bash shell's `,,` parameter expansion to do the case conversion inside a `find` command ex.

```
find Controls/ Patients/ -type d -name 'Caudate_masks' -execdir bash -c '
  for f; do mv "$f" "${f,,}"; done
' bash {} +
```